# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to do a console line calculator and there is a problem with my program. I call a method (startParsing) and pass a user input. My method works during the first iteration (when i=0) and it adds a number into my number property (which is @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *number; in my .h file) and adds an operator to the NSMutableArray. So if I pass 2+3+7, the method adds "2" to the number property and "+" to the array of operators. Then the second iteration begins and when this line is called [self.number appendFormat:@"%c", symbol]; the error appears: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'.

Can you please help me a little bit to understand what's wrong and how I can fix it?

```
- (void)startParsing:(NSMutableString *)userInput {

int operatorCounter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < [userInput length]; i++)
{
    char symbol = (char) [userInput characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger) i];

    if ([self isSymbolNumber:symbol])
    {
        [self.number appendFormat:@"%c", symbol]; 
        operatorCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self isOperatorSymbol:symbol])
        {
            //checks if the symbol is a unary operator.
            if ((symbol == '-' || symbol == '+') && ([self isSymbolNumber:(char) [userInput characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger) i + 1]])
                    && (operatorCounter == 1))
            {
                [self.number appendFormat:@"%c", symbol];
                operatorCounter = 0;

            }
            else if (operatorCounter == 0)
            {
                [self convertNumberToIntAndAddToArray:self.number];

                NSMutableString *singleCharacter  = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%c", symbol];
                [self.arrayOfOperators addObject:singleCharacter];

                operatorCounter++;
            }
            else [self printErrorWith:@"Invalid input operatorCounter == 0 "];
        }
        else
        {
            [self printErrorWith:@"Invalid input operatorCounter == 0 below"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, using char for the result of "characterAtIndex" is just awful. char is 8 bits, characterAtIndex is 16 bits. As soon as there are any non-ASCII characters, things will go badly wrong.

self.number is most likely an immutable string (NSString), so trying to append a char to it is not going to work. Methods starting with "stringBy" create and return a new string; look for something suitable.

Comment: thank mate for your answer. So if you think that self.number is an immutable string how can I make it mutable? When I declared it, it is a NSMutable string.  I did not quite get what you mean methods with stringBy. I need to find a suitable methods in documentation?

Comment: @splean stringWithFormat will return an immutable string instead you should use it  like {[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%c", symbol] mutableCopy]

Comment: @gnasher729 can you please check my comment? thanks.